# codesign --keychain gets ignored

Tags: ios, xcode, jenkins, xcodebuild, codesign

I am exporting App archives using the command line tools (`xcodebuild`). Essentially this is what I running:

```
xcodebuild -workspace "${WORKSPACE_PATH}" \
    -scheme "${SCHEME_NAME}" \
    -archivePath "${PROJECT_ARCHIVE}" \
    -configuration "${CONFIGURATION}" \
    -sdk "${TARGET_SDK}" \
    DEVELOPMENT_TEAM="XXXXXXXX" \
    OTHER_CODE_SIGN_FLAGS="--keychain /Users/user/Library/Keychains/jenkins.keychain" \
    archive
```

And this is the result:

```
Check dependencies
No signing certificate "iOS Development" found:  No "iOS Development" signing certificate matching team ID "XXXXXXX" with a private key was found.
Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 10.2'

** ARCHIVE FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
Check dependencies
(1 failure)
$ echo $?
65
```

The code signing fails because `codesign` ignores the --keychain parameter. Now here is the interesting part. The keychain I want to use is `jenkins.keychain-db` (as specified above). That certainly does not work. Here is my keychain search list:

```
$ security list-keychains
"/Users/user/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db"
"/Library/Keychains/System.keychain"
```

Obviously `jenkins.keychain-db` is not in there as it should be. If I am adding the `jenkins.keychain-db` in the search list it starts working.

**Unfortunately this is not a solution for me because I do have multiple keychains with the same private keys and certificates. That leads xcodebuild to pick up the first *right* certificate that it can find which will fails because the keychain is probably not unlocked.**

Answer (score 4):

You can make codesign prefer using your custom keychain with the following commands:

```
security list-keychains -d user -s jenkins.keychain
security default-keychain -s jenkins.keychain

# to unlock the kechain:
security unlock-keychain -p $PW jenkins.keychain
```

Put this right before *xcodebuild ...*

You can omit the -db extension. It's not necessary to use it and will lead to confusing behavior.

You might want to clean this up after the build has finished:

```
security list-keychains -d user -s login.keychain
security default-keychain -s login.keychain
```

Comment: Why only from sierra ?